# Pointer scope in C++

Tags: c++, scope

Although this is a very general question, here's my specific example so you can understand what I'm asking.

I have a copy constructor for a quad-tree class. So I write a recursive helper method called copy so I can call it in my copy constructor. The helper takes one parameter, a node. The root node is given as the first argument when called from the constructor.

So now in my helper method, I create one new node call it `newNode`, and each node has member variables neChild, nwChild, seChild, swChild----sw means southwest nw, ne, se are all cardinal directions, and I set each new child equal to that of source.child. Then I call the helper method again recursively on each source.child (4 of them). So this way, 1 node becomes 4, which then has 16 childs, and so on. And so then I return that first `newNode` I created.

#### Question:

Will that new returned node have all the other nodes attached to it? Will it be in a tree structure (although not formally a tree)? Or will those pointers attached to returned pointers go out of scope?

Comment: It will be much easier to understand if you post the code. We need to see how you are allocating memory for the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will end up with a new root node which is linked to the same child nodes as the original tree.  So any changes made to any children will affect both trees, and you may have a double-free problem later.

This is because, although you're calling `copy` recursively, you're discarding the return value.

Furthermore, you said this `copy` function is called from your copy constructor?  You're in for a world of hurt, because `copy` calls the copy constructor (at the return statement, since you return by value).  That's a recipe for a STACK OVERFLOW.  I guess you're in the right place ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, as others have pointed out, you are confusing `QuadtreeNode` and `QuadtreeNode*` when you create `newNode`. I'll assume it's a pointer.

Second, you're not guarding against NULLs well enough.

Third, if my reading of this code is correct, the four recursive calls to `copy` produce nothing but memory leaks; each call generates a new node on the heap, and returns a pointer to that new node, but your code does not retain that pointer. So `copy` will return a pointer to a new node, which has child pointers pointing to the children of the argument node-- and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff allocated from the *heap* will not go out of scope on function return. A local variable *pointing* to something on the heap would go out of scope but, if you're returning it from the function, then you're keeping a copy.

If, however, those variables are automatic (on the stack), they *will* go out of scope when you return.

And, based on your code, which was something like (not posting *actual* code since OP stated it was homework and they didn't want copies kept):

```
XTreeNode XTreeNode::copy(XTreeNode & const n) {
    XTreeNode *newNode = new XTreeNode(7);  // <-- Note "*", this is important.
    newNode.xy=n.xy;
    return newNode;
}
```

You have chosen the *third* of those two options I gave :-)

Because you are passing in `n`, it will still be in scope when you exit the function and the one thing that does go out of scope (`newNode`) is being returned anyway, so you will still have a copy.

Comment: @bitmoe, since this is an assignment, you should have marked it homework. In any case, even if you _delete_ your own code, it will still be visible in the edit history. But, I've modified the code to protect the guilty :-), whilst still retaining the essence.

Comment: @bitmoe, you can't ask for our help and also ask us not to help your classmates. The answers we post here are, for the most part, public and permanent-- that's how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are returning `QuadtreeNode*` from your `copy` method, the pointer you are returning from this function will remain valid outside this function until you manually release the memory using `delete`.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. If you are allocating memory for the node on stack (i.e doing `QuadtreeNode newNode;`) then see the answer from @paxdiablo. If you are allocating memory from heap (i.e. doing `QuadtreeNode* newNode = new QuadtreeNode(...);`, then you need to change the return type to `QuadtreeNode*` and change the accessing of the object from using `.` to `->`.

Answer (score 0):

If `newNode` type is `QuadtreeNode*`, then the way to access the member variables/methods is with `->` operator.

`newNode` lies on stack but the memory it is pointing to lies on heap( And this where the object lies in this case ). So, it is returning a reference to the location on the heap( If return type is `QuadtreeNode*`). Its fine. But, the program needs to deallocate the resources acquired from the heap/free store using `delete`, else memory leak prevails.